# Polymer 0.5, core-scaffold menu is not showing

Tags: polymer

In my Polymer 0.5 app, core-scaffold has stopped showing it's menu in latest version of Chrome(49).

Here is basic core-scaffold [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2KzBHouyDLeDE5HYSpEs?p=preview), Chrome dose not show the menu items.

It there some way to get the menu back?

```
<core-scaffold>
  <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
    <core-toolbar>Application</core-toolbar>
    <core-menu theme="core-light-theme">
      <core-item icon="settings" label="item1"></core-item>
      <core-item icon="settings" label="item2"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
  </core-header-panel>
  <div tool>Title</div>
  <div>
    Main content goes here...
  </div>
</core-scaffold>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Chrome bug https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3499 
The bug is already fixed in Canary (51).

> Chrome pre-49 erroneously supported ::content[attribute] as a synonym for attribute]::content (not surprisingly, because the spec is hella confusing).